# How to refer to browser global in typescript within another namespace of the same name

Tags: typescript

I'm learning TypeScript. I'm wondering how you would refer to the browsers global `Math` namespace within another namespace called Math like below:

```
namespace THREE {
    namespace Math {
        export function polar(...) {
            ...
            Math.acos(...) // How do I refer to global Math here?
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could achieve that by extending the type Window and then use `window.Math.acos`:

```
interface Window {
    Math: typeof Math;
}

namespace THREE {
    namespace Math {
        export function polar(...) {
            window.Math.acos(...)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Darin's answer. However, I would also advise not to name your namespace "Math" for the sake of readability of your code. It will be easy to get your own "Math" implementation and the window.Math library mixed up.

Comment: Right, I would generally agree; however, Three.js has already defined ```THREE.Math``` so it feels a little more natural to keep extra math functions in there in this case.